# Why does my loop occasionally not read the entire line?

Tags: bash, loops, scripting, filepath

I've been googling this problem for hours and have never encountered it before. I have a script that creates thumbnail gifs for instructional videos for my company PRN. When I run it the shell sometimes omits half of the filepath and therefore fails.

This is on a debian 9 machine (bash). I have tried plenty of ways to write the loop, including piping to a file (which is comes out correct) and then reading it back to a loop (which then blends my output). I've tried set `-x` from the first line of the script and it definitely seems to be a problem of the shell itself. The results also vary. Sometimes I put in a file and get 30 characters, sometimes it reads just 22, but it's always the same files that fail. `od -xa` shows no wrong characters in between.

This is my current loop start and also the point at which things start to fail so I won't bother posting the rest.

```sh
PPATH="/home/pi/pmount/prntest"

find "$PPATH" -type f -iname "*.mp4" >tempfile

cat -v tempfile | while read i
do
makethumbs "$i"
echo "$i" >>test.txt
done
```

e.g. the path of a file is `/home/pi/pmount/prntest/Security Training/Example #1.mp4`

Example output:

```
/prntest/Security Training/Example #1.mp4
```

or

```
urity Training/Example #1.mp4`
```

Of course this cannot be parsed. Any ideas? I'd be very grateful.

EDIT:

Required Info:

````
Shell: /bin/bash 

GNU bash, Version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 

Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u3 (2019-06-16) ```
````

Comment: You have spaces in your pat. Try without tmpfile like `find ...| while IFS= read -r ; do`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer but that is not the solution. As you can see with the example output, it sometimes cuts stuff off in the middle of a word. Lots of files with spaces in them work perfectly well.

Comment: If you do `find "$PPATH" -type f -name '*.mp4' | while read i; do echo "$i"; done` you have the correct value, I don't see any problem

Comment: Can't tell if it the `makethumbs` cmd that is failing or `echo "$i"`. Please boil this down to something like `echo "/home/pi/pmount/prntest/Security Training/Example #1.mp4" | makethumbs` or just `echo "/home/pi/pmount/prntest/Security Training/Example #1.mp4" >> test.txt`. Have you cleaned out your `test.txt` file lately, you aren't looking at the first interations wrong output, check the bottom of the file, or `> test.txt` to zero it out. I think you're going to have to post the `od -xa` output for your sample record. ....

Comment: Hmm.. Also, show us `echo $SHELL` and `eval $SHELL --version`. AND `uname -srv` . Good first Q! You have obviously put in the research! Keep posting and Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried to be as descriptive as possible. I have attached the information above in the edit section.

Comment: Did you try an `echo` as @shelter asked? Do you have a `\r` somewhere? Can you show the output of `cat -v tempfile` (lines that goes wrong)?
Do you have a problem when you remove the line with `makethumps`??

Comment: yes agree @WalterA : `cat -vet tempfile` and if you see `^M$` at the end lines, then run `dos2unix`. If not, then please edit Q to include 1 bad record filtered thru `od -xa`. Thanks for the version numbers, at least we know its not because you are doing this on HPUX or AIX or someother ancient system ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is preferred to output null `$'\0'` terminated entries rather than the newline character `$'\n'`.
The `-print0` option of the `find` command does exactly this.

Here is your corrected code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PPATH=/home/pi/pmount/prntest

find "$PPATH" -type f -iname "*.mp4" -print0 >tempfile # write null-terminated strings to tempfile

while read -r -d '' i # -r do not expand globbing characters and -d '' use a null delimiter
do
  makethumbs "$i"
  echo "$i" >>test.txt
done <tempfile # inject the tempfile for the whole loop
```

Comment: Thank you but this achieves the same result (although the way might be better). Still no luck here.

Answer (score 1):

Having find write to a file only to immediately read it is unnecessary. Also, why `cat -v`?

I would do this:

```
find "$PPATH" -type f -iname "*.mp4" -print -exec makethumbs {} ';' | tee test.txt
```

---

OK, `makethumbs` is a shell function. Still can stick with this approach:

```
export -f makethumbs 
find "$PPATH" -type f -iname "*.mp4" -print -exec bash -c '
    for file; do makethumbs "$file"; done
' _bash {} + | tee test.txt
```

Using the `-exec cmd {} +` form to pass multiple files at once to the command in order to minimize the number of bash shells spawned.

Need to export the function into the environment so that child shells can pick it up.

The "_bash" argument is required because, when passing arguments while using the `-c` option, the first argument is taken as `$0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that cat -v and and no directly piping the output were just some of the many things I've tried to fix this. Your approach won't work for me because exec cannot find functions local to shell. Your command would have me rewrite major parts of the script.

Comment: Thank you again for your edit, that will not work for me though because the exported function cannot access global variables.